# PHP get button ID

Tags: php, html, forms

Is it possible to get the button ID? I have accumulated forms and I wanted to get the button clicked using the unique ID. The following scripts I used:

```
echo("<table><tr>
    <td id=\"i\"><img src='presentations/uploaded_files/$name.png' alt='animal' width='50px' height='50px'/></td>
    <td id=\"n\">$name</td>
    <td id=\"d\">$dsc</td>
    <td id=\"t\">$type</td>
    <td id=\"g\">$grade</td>
    <td id=\"b\">
    <form enctype=\"multipart/form-data\" action=\"admin_update_animal.php\" method=\"POST\"><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Update\" name=\"update\" id=\"$name\"/></form></td>
</tr></table>");
```

I used the following when any of the button clicked:

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])) { 
$f=trim($_POST['update']);
}
```

But I wanted to get which button clicked using its unique ID assigned.
I am very glad for a help. Thanks.

Comment: php deals with name only

Comment: You can do that only using Javascript to store ID somewhere in hidden field with some name of it. ID is not passing via $_POST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly read the **id** of a control because **name** is passed to the server side script via any **methods**. You can use **hidden input fields** whose **value** can be the **id** of the **button**. This lets you know the **id** of the **button** in the server side.
This can be done as:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function createField(id)
  {
         var x = document.getElementById("hide");
         var y = "<input type='hidden' name='iddetector' value='"+id+"'/>";
         x.innerHTML = y;
        return;
  }
</script>
//maintain other stuffs here and now
<input type="submit" id="uniqueid" name="submit" value="submit"onClick="createField('uniqueid');return true;"/><br>
<div id="hide"></div>

You can detect the id of the button i the sever side as:-
 <?php
    $idButton = isset($_POST['iddetector'])?$_POST['iddetector']:NULL;
     echo "The id of the button clicked is ".$idButton;
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is passed via `POST` is the `name` of the control, not the `id`. To capture the ID you would be better off using JavaScript before submit.

The point is that you may have multiple controls in different places in the page with the same name (but different IDs) that perform the same task (like submit).

Comment: Thank you for the additional Info. :)